# Django filtering model on datetime with interger and datetime

Tags: python, django, database

I try to make a query to select all the object that where modified since a specified time
This time is `now - max_schedule_delay` where `max_schedule_delay` is a data from the object (see code sample below).

I try multiple thing .. but here I am. Maybe you will be able to help me find a way.

## Environment

- python 2.7
- django 1.11

database : Posgresql

## Sample code

```py
from django.db import models

class MyObject(models.Model):
    # last modification date
    mtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, db_index=True)
    # maximum delay before rescheduling in seconds
    max_schedule_delay = models.IntegerField()
```

## What I want to achieve

```sql
select * from MyObject where (mtime + max_schedule_delay > now)
```

## My tests

```py
from django.db.models import F, ExpressionWrapper,, TimeField, DateTimeField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

MyObject.objects.filter(max_schedule_delay__lte=now - F("mtime")) # here max_schedule_delay is a integer, so this query is not possible

# I try to split this query in two, but still not wotking
MyObject.objects.annotate(threshold=ExpressionWrapper(now - F("max_schedule_delay"), output_field=DateTimeField())).filter(mtime__gte=F("threshold"))

MyObject.objects.annotate(threshold=ExpressionWrapper(F("mtime") + F("max_schedule_delay"), output_field=DateTimeField())).filter(threshold__gte=now)

MyObject.objects.annotate(as_date=Cast("max_schedule_delay", TimeField()))
```

Any help is welcome,
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, and based on the post [Using dateadd in django filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33981468/using-dateadd-in-django-filter) I was able to do something, but only for posgresql

```py
from django.db.models import Func, DateTimeField
import datetime

class DateAdd(Func):
    """
    Custom Func expression to add date and int fields as day addition
    Usage:
    Model.objects.annotate(annotation=DateAdd('field_date','field_seconds'))
    """
    arg_joiner = " + CAST("
    template = "%(expressions)s || ' seconds' as INTERVAL)"
    output_field = DateTimeField()

MyModel.objects.annotate(
        threshold=DateAdd("mtime", "max_schedule_delay")
    ).filter(
        max_schedule_delay__isnull=False,
        state=botSession.STATE.DONE,
        threshold__lte=datetime.datetime.now()
    )
```